# HTML, CSS design image out of grid

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I have the following design and want to implement it with bootstrap:

[image]

as you see the image should start from 8th grid and go all the way to the end of the page out of grid layout I have created a working snippet in codepen:

```
`https://codepen.io/zakarya-noori/pen/KKGQMJo`
```

here is my code:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683339708262-b1208394ffec?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you put your code on here instead of CodePen? Thank you.

Comment: @Apodemus sure I have added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap sets the max width dependent on the media query then uses margin: auto to center the content. You could push the image to the edge by setting margin-right to zero then adding the gutter width to the overall width of the image.  I've had to increase the specificity of the .container rule to make it override boostrap's default.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: calc(100% + var(--bs-gutter-x,.75rem));
  height: 600px;
}

main > .container {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683339708262-b1208394ffec?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Edited to add: Here's a solution using Javascript to listen to the window resize event and size the image accordingly.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', setImageWidth);
  setImageWidth();
}

function setImageWidth() {
  const img = document.querySelector('#myimage');
  const imgRect = img.getBoundingClientRect();
  const mainRect = document.querySelector('#mymain').getBoundingClientRect();
  img.style.width = (mainRect.width - imgRect.x) +"px";
}
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main id='mymain'>
  <div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
        <h1>Right side text <br> and title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-5">
        <img id='myimage' src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683339708262-b1208394ffec?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Image showing margins are the same below:
[image]

Comment: Now the page is shifting to the right as its margin right is 0 so left margin is getting twice as big as it must be

Comment: I've added a way to control the width in JS using event listeners.

Comment: the problem is with the container if you check your example your container has so much margin from left almost twice as it should be

Comment: For the javascript example, the margins are the same. I've uploaded an image to show this.